# saving Oracle XMLType type column using JPA

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, jpa

I have a column type defined in Oracle as XMLTYPE and I am trying to save xml content using JPA. I have used something like in my entity class.

```
@CLOB
@Column(name = "COLOUM_NAME")
private String coloumName;
```

But i am getting the following exception.

> ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Any solution for above issue?

Comment: did you find a solution to this ?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need @CLOB annotation here. Just use String type.

Comment: still getting the same error ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Comment: Are you sure your problem really with this column? Could you show create statement and entity?